# How do I get the windows logged in User email ID from Outside domain

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-authentication

I want to get windows logged in user email address when my site is hosted on Standalone server outside my domain. I need to access user email id only inside domain when any one go to the site. I'm using MVC 5 with .Net 4.5.

I've tried windows authentication which doesn't work. When I try to get email id from following code, it's empty although these are on Active Directory.

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress;
```

Comment: How are your users logging in from that standalone server?

Comment: Form Authentication as of now, which I need to Migrate to Active Directory Authentication. On test server, I used Windows Authentication Enabled , Impersonate True and Anonymous authentication disabled.